# Ubuntu 22.04 Qemu Could not access KVM kernel module: Permission denied

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to setup Windows 10 with GPU passthrough [with this guide](https://gitlab.com/risingprismtv/single-gpu-passthrough/-/wikis/home). When I launch the domain it throws KVM kernel error. VM without passthrough worked flawlessly.

output of ls -ld /dev/kvm

`crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root kvm 10, 232 sep  8 17:42 /dev/kvm`

contents of /etc/udev/rules.d/65-kvm.rules

`KERNEL=="kvm", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0666"`

*note*: I had to create this file by myself

contents of /var/log/libvirt/qemu/win10.log

```
...
-device ich9-intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1b \
-device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0,audiodev=audio1 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=2 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1,bus=usb.0,port=3 \
-device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.4,addr=0x0 \
-sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny \
-msg timestamp=on
audio: Could not init `spice' audio driver
audio: warning: Using timer based audio emulation
Could not access KVM kernel module: Permission denied
2022-07-14T17:59:18.594088Z qemu-system-x86_64: -accel kvm: failed to initialize kvm: Permission denied
2022-07-14 17:59:18.676+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-08-25 09:53:10.580+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 13:58:04.803+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 14:18:31.434+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 14:32:29.145+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 14:42:06.994+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 14:44:22.631+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 14:54:31.428+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 15:15:21.686+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 15:17:29.841+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
2022-09-08 15:42:04.487+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
```

other logs seem to be fine

Trying this on Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6H

Could it be caused by Spice audio driver not initializing?

Comment: The guide you linked does a lot of user/permission changes which would on Ubuntu be correct out of the box. For example in step 4 it sets the user from "root" to "your username" - but in Ubuntu that already would have been a special group - which is better than giving the guest permission to reach all your stuff. IT does further things which are not needed as they'd work, but due to the changes in the guide are then broken. Have a look at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-libvirt in section Device Passthrough, that should be all you need.

Comment: I appreciate that the tutorial you used is really step by step, but also not 100% applicable to Ubuntu. I'll try have a look at writing a more tutorial style (instead of a few non connected howto sections) for this later this year. While I couldn't help much I wanted to thank for the hint. I have written a bit more about (different) GPU attachments here https://cpaelzer.github.io/blogs/006-mediated-device-to-pass-parts-of-your-gpu-to-a-guest/

Comment: Thanks for your informative response! I'll definitely have a look at it.